# Roblox GUI Kill Brick

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm learning LUA and trying to make a GUI that spawns a brick above the players head which kills the player if touched. I'm not sure how to to connect the Touched event to a part that's spawned in with Instance.new? Here's what I got so far!

```
local button = script.Parent
local function kill()
    button.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 4)
    button.parent.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 4)
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer.character
    local killBrick = Instance.new("Part")
    killBrick.Name = "Kill Brick"
    killBrick.CFrame = player.Head.CFrame*CFrame.new(0,10,0)
    killBrick.Parent = game.Workspace
    killBrick.Color = Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 0)
    killBrick.Material = "Neon"
    killBrick.BottomSurface = "Smooth"
    killBrick.TopSurface = "Studs"
    button.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(80, 80, 255)
    button.parent.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(106, 146, 255)
end
button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(kill)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing:

```lua
    killBrick.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
        if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
            hit.Parent.Humanoid.Health=0
        end
    end)
```